# I am unable to read data into my Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I cloned a repo from GitHub to the Google Cloud Workbench. I haven't been able to read in my data to the Jupyter notebook. It seems like it is unable to locate the file. I have checked the file spellings and location, it all seems to be in place. I also tried to read it in as

```
PATH = "data/countypres_2000-2020.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
```

or as

```
PATH = "eco395m-homework-6/data/countypres_2000-2020.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
```

[image]

[image] [image: The data file exists in the expected directory]

[image]

Comment: Try using the path: `./../data/countypres_2000-2020.csv`. I'm assuming you're reading data in a jupyter notebook present inside the `code/` directory. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PATH = r"/data/countypres_2000-2020.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
```